# How to pass image values from python to kv file in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to pass the image source value to kv file in kivy. This is what I have done.

```
#main.py
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class Page(BoxLayout):  
    id1=StringProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        super(Page, self).__init__()
        self.id1="ellow"
        self.img=StringProperty("logo.jpg") 



class SimpleKivyApp(App):  

    def build(self):        
        return Page()

a=SimpleKivyApp()
a.run()
```

KV file

```
#simplekivy.kv
<Page>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 

    Image:          
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.4,"y":0.3}
        color:255,1,1,1
        size:70,70
        source: root.img

    Label:      
        pos:0,0
        font_size:80
        text:root.id1

    Button:
        size_hint:0.5,0.2       
        font_size:60
        text:"Start"
        on_press:  app.onClick()
```

when I run this its giving me this error

> AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'img'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kv file is first evaluated during the widget´s `__init__` method. This occurs in `super` call, before you set `self.img`. You must declare the atribute before `super` or declare a property as class attribute and not as instance attribute. You can do it in the `py` (as you do with `id1`) or in `kv`:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kv_text = '''
#simplekivy.kv
<Page>:
    img: ''                    #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 

    Image:          
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.4,"y":0.3}
        color:255,1,1,1
        size:70,70
        source: root.img

    Label:      
        pos:0,0
        font_size:80
        text:root.id1

    Button:
        size_hint:0.5,0.2       
        font_size:60
        text:"Start"
        on_press:  app.onClick()
'''


class Page(BoxLayout):  
    id1=StringProperty()
    def __init__(self):
        super(Page, self).__init__()
        self.id1="ellow"
        self.img="logo.jpg"

class SimpleKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv_text)     
        return Page()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleKivyApp().run()
```